# How can I create a List of Razor Page in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, blazor

I'm trying to create a list of razor page.
I explain myself,
in my "Index.razor", I actually have that :

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1 style="text-align:center;color:red" >Hey :)</h1>
<br />
<Counter/>
<NewCounter/>
<AnotherVersion/>
```

Who redirect to Counter.razor, NewCounter.razor & AnotherVersion.razor.

but, like a string list I want to create something like that :
having a list like that :

```
List<Page> myPage = new List<Page>{Counter, NewCounter, AnotherVersion};
```

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1 style="text-align:center;color:red" >Hey :)</h1>
<br />
@for(int i = 0; i < myPage.Count; i++)
{
    myPage[i];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a list of pages".  Do you mean a list of <a> links to pages?

Comment: Yes, I have a bad english, so it' hard to understand me, but I want to store in a list the link to pages

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to be sure that I understood what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay someone post the answer and delete it right after.

So, here the answer :

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1 style="text-align:center;color:@bgColor" >My Dashboard</h1>
<br />
@foreach (var component in widget)
{
    <DynamicComponent Type=@component />
}

@code {
    public System.Type[] widget =
    new[] { typeof(Counter), typeof(NewCounter), typeof(AnotherVersion) };
}
```

(If he repost his message, I will delete mine)